# android onDestroy

Tags: android

is there a way i can delay the OS from killing my app... it runs in the background with a countdowntimer but its not a service... is there a way to raise its prioity or something so that it stay in the background for as long as possible and is still running when the application is resumed

Answer (score 3):

An activity should only be displaying things to the user.  Any processing should be done in a service.

Comment: it isnt a service because it extends CountDownTimer

Comment: Consider putting your CountDownTimer in an IntentService http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html  I find this an easy way to offload ongoing processing from an activity.   More importantly, the processing will continue till it's done.   You can use the starting intent to send whatever data you need.